# How to add a piece of text after a div? ( React-js, Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

A very noob question. So I'm practicing making this website. How can I achieve this : I want to be able to write " To know more about us click here " under the get started button. I tried adding a simple  tag after the buttons div to do so but that doesn't work. This is what I want it to finally look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqAD9.png

if it helps this is the whole website hosted on netfy : https://pinnacletrial.netlify.app/

Here's the code : The current page is HOME.jsx and it calls a component Common.jsx
COde of home.jsx:   ---

```
import React from "react";
import web from "../src/images/myimage.svg";
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";
import Common from './Common';
import CarouselContainer from "./CarouselContainer";
import Aboutrefer from "./aboutrefer";



const Home =()  => {
    return (
         <>
         <CarouselContainer/>
        
         <Common name ='Learn with' imgsrc = {web} visit ='/service' btnname='Get started' />
        
       </>
         
         
        
         

     
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Code of Common.js    ----

```
import React from "react";
import web from "../src/images/myimage.svg";
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";


const Common =(props)  => {
    return (
         <>

         
          <section id = "header" className = "d-flex align-items-between  ">
          <div className = "container-fluid">
            <div className = 'row'>
                <div className = "col-12" mx-auto>
               
                  <div className ="row">  
                  

                  
                  <div className = "col-md-6 pt-5 pt-lg-0 order-2 order-lg-1 d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
                    <h1>{props.name} <strong className = "brand-name"> Pinnacle Tutorials</strong>
                    </h1>
                    <h2 className = "my-3">
                       We are a team of talented Teachers here for your ward
                     </h2>
                     <div ClassName = "mt-3">
                         <NavLink to={props.visit} className = "btn btn-success">Get Started {props.btname}</NavLink>
                     </div>

                  </div>
                  <div className = "col-lg-6   order-6 order-lg-5  header-img  d-flex justify-content-end">
                    <img src ={props.imgsrc} className = "img animated" alt = "home img "/>

                  </div>
                  
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>  
          </section>
         </>

     
    );
};

export default Common;
```

Comment: just add `<div className="mt-1">To know more about us click here</div>` after the div of the button. it is working w/o problems

Comment: Great, but how do I add a space between the two ? I did what you said, but it's very close to each other.

Comment: just change mt-1 to mt-3 or mt-2 or mt-4. check the space and decide what fits best!

Answer (score 0):

You have div with class name "row". I would add the new div with the same class name "row" below it, because row in bootstrap means that blocks will stack on top of each other with occupying the full width of the container.

*Common.js*:

```
<div className="row">
    ....
    <h2 className = "my-3">
        We are a team of talented Teachers here for your ward
    </h2>
    ....
</div>
<div className="row">
     To know more about us click here
</div>
```

Comment: Great, but how do I add a space between the two ? I did what you said, but it's very close to each other.

Comment: To do so, you need to add margin between rows.

Comment: <div className="row" style={{marginBottom: "20px"}}>...</div>
<div className="row">To know more about us click here</div>

Comment: Great, it works but the image on right also increases in size when i increase margin ? How can i keep the size of the image on the right fixed? By "image" I meant the animated image right next to the get started button. Please tell.

Comment: Try to change it to this:
<div className="row">...</div> <div className="row"  style={{paddingBottom: "20px"}}>To know more about us click here</div>

Answer (score 0):

You can just write it down after the **NavLink** in `Common.js` like:

Example:

```
<h2 className = "my-3">
  We are a team of talented Teachers here for your ward
</h2>
<div ClassName = "mt-3">
  <NavLink to={props.visit} className = "btn btn-success">Get Started {props.btname</NavLink>
</div>

To know more about us, click here <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
```

Complete code:

```
import React from "react";
import web from "../src/images/myimage.svg";
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";


const Common =(props)  => {
    return (
         <>

         
          <section id = "header" className = "d-flex align-items-between  ">
          <div className = "container-fluid">
            <div className = 'row'>
                <div className = "col-12" mx-auto>
               
                  <div className ="row">  
                  

                  
                  <div className = "col-md-6 pt-5 pt-lg-0 order-2 order-lg-1 d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
                    <h1>{props.name} <strong className = "brand-name"> Pinnacle Tutorials</strong>
                    </h1>
                    <h2 className = "my-3">
                       We are a team of talented Teachers here for your ward
                     </h2>
                     <div ClassName = "mt-3">
                         <NavLink to={props.visit} className = "btn btn-success">Get Started {props.btname}</NavLink>
                     </div>

To know more about us, click here <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>

                  </div>
                  <div className = "col-lg-6   order-6 order-lg-5  header-img  d-flex justify-content-end">
                    <img src ={props.imgsrc} className = "img animated" alt = "home img "/>

                  </div>
                  
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>  
          </section>
         </>

     
    );
};

export default Common;
```

Comment: Great, but how do I add a space between the two ? I did what you said, but it's very close to each other.